# CoreData get parent of child

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a `one-to-many` relationship `store <---->> product`, and I know the product, how can I find out who the parent of this product is? I can have many products with the same values, for example `product1` has `parent1` and another product with the same values as `product1` has `parent2` so i cant't search which parent contains `product1`?

Comment: Presumable 'parent' means 'store' in your description? Also, if you have duplicate products why aren't you instead using a many:many relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have noticed the core data model editor bugging you about the relationship not having an *inverse relationship* if you don't have one. If you do have one, it's as simple as using that key.

Hypothetically, `store` has a relationship `products` - so each `product` should have a relationship `store`.